# Image manipulation in javascript

Tags: javascript, api, image-manipulation, image-editor

I am doing a project where we upload images and get a customized image as an output.

For example, when we take a picture from the Oneplus phone, we get their tag line at the image's bottom right Or something like the WFH DP on Facebook (adding templates to our image). We have to make something similar to this.

We are using NodeJS Multer for image uploading. The customization should be done in the backend. Can anybody help me how to proceed with this? Are there any APIs for custom image editing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not really the right site for "guide me through this" kinds of questions. As the [tour] notes, "This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat." It's also not a recommendation site, so we can't answer the question asking for "any APIs for custom image editing". I encourage you to take that [tour] and read the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

you can edit your image on canvas even backend

here is `canvas` module on npm

https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas

you can use almost function on canvas as a canvas in HTML as possible